# CMake specify sources before linking

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I have the following CMakeLists :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(untitled)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/home/kernael/.openmpi/include -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/kernael/.openmpi/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/home/kernael/.openmpi/lib -lmpi_cxx -lmpi")

add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

But the build seems to fail because CMake automatically specifies the sources (main.cpp) after the "-l" options, which seems to be the problem because with command line, the following command works :

```
g++ -I/home/kernael/.openmpi/include -pthread -L/home/kernael/.openmpi/lib main.cpp -lmpi_cxx -lmpi
```

But this one doesn't and produces the same errors as the CMake build :

```
g++ -I/home/kernael/.openmpi/include -pthread -L/home/kernael/.openmpi/lib -lmpi_cxx -lmpi main.cpp
```

How can I tell CMake to specify the source files before the links happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to investigate the following CMake commands:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html

Something like this should get the job done:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
add_executable(untitled main.cxx)
target_include_directories(untitled PUBLIC /home/kernael/.openmpi/include)
target_link_libraries(untitled -pthread -L/home/kernael/.openmpi/lib -lmpi_cxx -lmpi)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for includes in CMake, it is only for compiler options.

You have to find MPI with `find_package`. CMake then finds the include path, and the library.

```
find_package(MPI)
if (MPI_C_FOUND)
  include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
  add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
  target_link_libraries(untitled ${MPI_LIBRARIES})
  set_target_properties(untitled PROPERTIES
                        COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
else()
  # MPI not found ...
endif()
```